# Find Minimum Score from 4 column of Database

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I find a minimum score from 4 different column of table?
So, if I have column 1 with minimum value is 4, column 2 with minimum value is 3, column 3 with minimum value is 2 and column 4 with minimum value is 1. I want the query is making the result exactly is 1 (from column 1, 2, 3 and 4)

By the way i am using MYSQL, thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [LEAST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) function in following way:

```
  SELECT LEAST(t.column1, t.column2,t.column3,t.column4) AS lowest
                                                        FROM table_name t
```

From above mentioned documentation,

- If the return value is used in an INTEGER context or all arguments
  are integer-valued, they are compared as integers.
- If the return value is used in a REAL context or all arguments are
  real-valued, they are compared as reals.
- If the arguments comprise a mix of numbers and strings, they are
  compared as numbers.
- If any argument is a nonbinary (character) string, the arguments are
  compared as nonbinary strings.
- In all other cases, the arguments are compared as binary strings.

Answer (score 2):

```
select least(col1, col2, col3, col4) from your_table
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
SELECT LEAST(MIN(column1), MIN(column2), MIN(column3),MIN(column3)) AS Minimum_of_all
from table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try least() ([documentation here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least)):

```
select least(col1, col2, col3, col4) from table;
```